# Bios splash screen freeze after removing Ubuntu

Tags: freeze, windows-10, bios

Last week I went from single boot Ubuntu to dual boot windows 10 with Ubuntu. Now I wanted to change that to only windows 10 for performance reasons since the notebook is quite old.

So I read that removing Ubuntu is not as simple as it seems, so I made precautions and made backups of my data and started removing the partitions and extending the windows partition using partition wizard.

Afterwards I wanted to execute the commands via a live cd to fix the windows bootloader since this would be broken by now.

However after the forced restart by the partition wizard, my notebook freezes at the mb splash screen, giving me no option to boot from cd or Usb or to enter the bios screen.

This problem only occurs when the hard disk is connected.

I've tried cutting the power and removing the battery itself as well as changing the boot order by first booting without connected hdd, but none of this works.

I don't quite see what I can do anymore except for buying a new one so I hoped some of you might have some suggestions.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me when you said you want to switch to Windows 10 because your notebook is old. If you are concerned about your aging hardware, you are in fact better off installing Ubuntu with a lightweight desktop environment (or even a window manager) than installing Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your EFI bootloader info for Windows was stored in Ubuntu's /boot partition.  If that's the case, you need to somehow get Windows (boot from DVD?) to re-create those Windows system files.  I did this once, about a year ago, and couldn't tell you how I did it  Maybe I just backed-up everything and re-installed. It took a long time to figure out.  Look in the Microsoft Knowledge Base, as it's almost certainly a Windows problem, at this point.